# What is the role of `slotShared attribute?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

For what is the `slotShared` attribute on each slot in the pages request response used for?

```
{
 "slotId" : "FooterSlot",
 "slotUuid" : "eyJpdGV",
 "position" : "Footer",
 "name" : "Footer",
 "slotShared" : true,
 "components" : {
 "component" : [ {} ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`slotShared` tells you if the slot is shared by multiple pages. For example, a slot for a header or a logo could be shared/used by different pages.